# IOS, AdobeCreativeSDK C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, adobecreativesdk

I am relatively new to IOS App development and started learning it in Swift. Now I want to use the **Adobe Creative SDK**. Unfortunately all the sample codes are in C. So I would like to ask if somebody could shortly translate me the following basic example (given by [AdobeCreativeSDK ImageEditor UI guide](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/imageeditor/index.html)) into swift

```
- (void)displayEditorForImage:(UIImage *)imageToEdit
{
    AdobeUXImageEditorViewController *editorController = [[AdobeUXImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImage:imageToEdit];
    [editorController setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I already tried an online converter ([Swiftify](https://objectivec2swift.com/)), which created the following content:

```
func displayEditorForImage(imageToEdit: UIImage) {
    var editorController: AdobeUXImageEditorViewController = AdobeUXImageEditorViewController(image: imageToEdit)
    editorController.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(editorController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}
```

and XCode is telling me

> Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'AdobeUXImageEditorViewControllerDelegate?'

which I cannot interpret neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah already got it working...
The Swift code is given by:

```
let editorController = AdobeUXImageEditorViewController(image: UIImage(data: data!)!)
self.presentViewController(editorController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

,where I also deleted the Delegate.